# Python: Finding strings in a list containing an interval and replacing this interval by every number in it

Tags: python, pandas, list

I'm wondering if there's any beautiful/clean way of doing what I'm trying to :).
(I'm sure there is)
So My function receives a list of strings that can either contains strings in 2 format:
"12,13,14,15" or "12 to 15"
The goal is to parse the second type and replace the "to" by the numbers in the interval.

Delimiters between numbers doesn't matter, a regex will do the job after.
Here is pseudo code and an ugly implementation

The idea is to replace "to" in the list by the numbers in the interval so that I can easily parse numbers with a regex afterwards

```py
# The list is really inconsistent, separators may change and it's hand filled so some comments like in the last example might be present
l = ["12,13,14,15",
     "12 to 18",
     "10,21,22 to 42",
     "14,48,52",
     "12,14,22;45 and also 24 to 32"
]

def process_list(l):
  for x in l:
     if "to" in x:
         # Find the 2 numbers around the to and replace the "to" by ",".join(list([interval of number]))
  final_list = numero_regex.findall(num)
  return final_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need regex:

```
def process_list(l):
    final_list = []
    for s in l:
        l2 = []
        for n in s.split(','):
            params = n.split(' to ')
            nums = list(range(int(params[0]), int(params[-1])+1))
            l2.extend(nums)
        final_list.append(l2)
    return final_list
```

Output:

```
>>> process_list(l)

[[12, 13, 14, 15],
 [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
 [10, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42],
 [14, 48, 52]]
```

**Update**:

> I wanted an output for this case like this ["12,21,32;14, and the 12,13,14,15,[...],40"]. Which I can really easily parse with a regex

If you just want to replace 'number1 to number2', you can do:

```
def process_list(l):
    def to_range(m):
        return ','.join([str(i) for i in range(int(m.group('start')),
                                               int(m.group('stop'))+1)])
    return [re.sub(pat, to_range, s) for s in l]
```

Output:

```
# l = ["12,21,18 to 20;32;14, and the 12 to 16"]
>>> process_list(l)
['12,21,18,19,20;32;14, and the 12,13,14,15,16']
```

Comment: Nice answer I really like it. The reason I'll be using a regex is that the list is really messy.
Some elements could be like this: ["12,21,32;14, and the 12 to 40"]
Not consistant separator so I wanted an output for this case like this ["12,21,32;14, and the 12,13,14,15,[...],40"].
Which I can really easily parse with a regex

Comment: That's beautiful ! Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
from itertools import chain
def split(s):
    return list(chain(*(list(range(*list(map(int, x.split(' to ')))))+[int(x.split(' to ')[1])]
                        if ' to ' in x else
                        [int(x)]
                        for x in s.split(',')
                       )))
    
[split(e) for e in l]
```

output:

```
[[12, 13, 14, 15],
 [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
 [10, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42],
 [14, 48, 52]]
```

edit: I adapted the above solution to be used with regexex:

```
from itertools import chain
def split(s):
    regex = re.compile('(\d+\s*to\s*\d+|\d+)')
    return list(chain(*([int(x)] if x.isnumeric() else 
                        list(range(*map(int, re.split('\s+to\s+', x))))
                        +[int(re.split('\s+to\s+', x)[-1])]
                        for x in regex.findall(s)
                       )))
```

Comment: Nice answer I really like it. The reason I'll be using a regex is that the list is really messy. Some elements could be like this: ["12,21,32;14, and the 12 to 40"] Not consistant separator so I wanted an output for this case like this ["12,21,32;14, and the 12,13,14,15,[...],40"]. Which I can really easily parse with a regex –

Comment: @JulesSpender note that you can use `re.split` to combine it with regexes ;) For instance `re.split('[,;]')`